# Component similar to DevExpress ASPxTreeList (mix of Grid and TreeView) but for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, treeview

I'm looking for a component similar to ASPxTreeList (mix of Grid and TreeView) from DevExpress, but suitable to use in MVC 4:

http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxTreeListDemos/

My general requirements are:

- tree structure with a few additional columns,
- possibility of using images in some cells,
- possibility of sorting by each column (optional).

I was looking at Kendo UI with it's TreeView control with it's templating option:

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/templates.html

Problem is that probably it's not possible to fully simulate table layout using a tree based on ul/li elements. Maybe there are any jQuery solutions which solve that problem?

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) and its TreeGrid functionality (the demo is in the *"New in version 3.5"* section).

You can also check following demos of how to use it in ASP.NET MVC:

- [jqGrid in ASP.NET MVC - Strongly typed helper](http://tpeczek.codeplex.com/releases/view/62741)
- [jqGrid in ASP.NET MVC 3 and Razor](http://tpeczek.codeplex.com/releases/view/61796)

Comment: Looks nice, but this is component closer to grid than to tree. It's possible to create hierarchy there, but subgrids have separate column layout. I need to have a tree with columns, so something between tree and grid.

Comment: @HappyMole Are you sure you have looked at TreeGrid sample not SubGrid sample (those are two different things)?

Comment: OK, I didn't notice that sample - they're smartly hidden in the tree ;). Looks like something I'm looking for -> I'm going to evaluate that to see if it fills all my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The [DevExpress MVC TreeList extension](http://mvc.devexpress.com/TreeList/DataBinding) is available in the latest release: [DXperience ASP.NET v2012.2](http://devexpress.com)

Answer (score 1):

There is an equivalent for MVC from DevExpress. The component offer almost all the functionalities of the webform's one.

Look at the [MVC's demo page](http://mvc.devexpress.com/TreeView/Features)

Comment: No, it doesn't fit one of my requirements: additional columns -> ASPxTreeList is a mix of TreeView with Grid, your proposal is a simple TreeView.

Comment: You're rigth I missed that one. Also in the support they say that they are working on it, but it's still TBD.

Comment: Unfortunately they was writing that also 2 years ago, that's why I'm looking for other solutions.

Comment: For anyone trawling this page, it does now exist: http://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxTreeListDemos